Selenium website madness - I'm attempting to use selenium in Python script to open claude ai website and can't log in automatically to my account
I am a Python neophyte.  I had claude generate a script that would allow me to capture the contents of a claude session and to use it as pyttsx3 input and output this with my system voice.  My first attempt was for Chrome and as this did not work this present attempt is for Firefox.  Both attempts opened the correct web browser but as Selenium is involved as a remote agent (if that's the right word) both attempts were problematic.
this is claude ai address line when website opened
Below please find the first part of my script ending where firefox driver is called:
import os
desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
gecko_driver_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'geckodriver', 'geckodriver.exe')
print(f"GeckoDriver path: {gecko_driver_path}")  # For debugging
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pyttsx3
import time

def setup_driver():
    gecko_driver_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'geckodriver', 'geckodriver.exe')
    
    print(f"GeckoDriver path: {gecko_driver_path}")  # For debugging
    
    service = Service(gecko_driver_path)
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    options.set_preference("browser.privatebrowding.autostart", True)
    
    return webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)

I'm assuming that there may be either common selenium option statements or firefox options statement that will allow me to run script and open claude ai session.  What do I do next???
See above.  I expected claude ai to open, greet me on my account page and ask how it could help.

as is, your code doesn't log you in.  By default Selenium will launch the browser using a fresh, temporary profile.
